# vietnamsese character not saving in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

I cannot insert vietnamese characters in database through java program
when i insert into column name just like this : `"?ang làm vi?c"`

but when i execute sql query in Mysql workbench  :

`update location set address1 = 'đang làm việc' where location_id = 122;`

it works good.

Comment: Try specifying mysql to use unicode in the connection string: E.g. `"jdbc:mysql://localhost?useUnicode=true&characterSetResults=utf8&characterEncodi‌​ng=UTF-8"`

Comment: i tried. but, it's not working for me